# Apache2 not displaying any messages on restart

Tags: server, apache2, 15.04, webserver

When I use the following command to restart apache2 `service apache2 restart`.
I would usually get the output `* Restarting web server apache2` or if there are any errors with it would show the errors. I recently updated my server from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 and since then apache2 outputs are not showing up.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? And is there anyway to enable theses messages?

Thank for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no output if there is no error and you should now use `systemctl`, e.g.:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

To show the status

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

Comment: Can you explain why sometimes (on some servers) there's an output and sometimes there isn't? I'm working on a project where there *is* output, but I just started my own VPS and there *isn't* output.